# How to integrate YouTube API authentication into my iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I am developing one application which needs the youtube user authentication ?How can I integrate youtube login in my app ? Any tutorials ?After the authentication I need to send the comment,like to specific videos

pls help me

Answer (score 3):

You need to check out the Google Objective-C Client Library and the Google Toolbox for Mac.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/

The toolbox handles OAuth2, and the Objective-C client handles API operations for all Google Services.

Comment: Do you have any sample project?

Comment: The google objective-c api client contains sample projects

Answer (score 0):

You can go through these url's to know the procedure of how to integrate `GData` API in Objective C.

http://mischneider.comli.com/blog/?p=377

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVMkRUhibsk